# Angular 6 in HTML if field is undefined show Not applicable

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am receiving a return from an API call and I need to populate a field in a table with all the results. The return has a `type` attribute but out of the four different outcomes, one does not have the attribute `type`.

So in the html I want the `type` to be shown within the table using *ngfor i have set up but where the lack of `type` would be empty due to it not existing i would like to show N/A or not applicable.

How could i implement this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `||` for this.

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of items">
    <td>{{ item.type || 'N.A.' }}
</tr>
```

If item.type is falsy (null, undefined, 0, empty string etc.) it will take the second value, which is simply the string 'N.A.'.

Comment: You're welcome. Consider accepting the answer if it has helped you.